# WebStorm starts with DEBUG mode, exit with "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

[Windows] WebStorm starts with DEBUG mode, exit with "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)", but when I starts with RUN mode, it won't happen.

[image]

Comment: 0xC0000005 is the Windows error code for an Access Violation. For some reason, debugging your program causes an access violation. Without knowing anything about the details of your program, it's hard to help.

Comment: what Node.js version is it? exit code -1073741819 indicates 'access violation' error; this is likely a Node V8 issue

Comment: There are some issues, this error does not always occur, the probability of this is uncertain. My node version is v14.18.2